Continuous function with limits $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{f(x_0+t)-f(x_0-t)}{t}\geq0$.
Here's a question for the midterm:
Function $f(x)\in C[a, b]$, for $\forall x_0 \in [a, b]$, $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{f(x_0+t)-f(x_0-t)}{t}\geq0$.Proof that $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing.
For $f(x) \in C^1[a, b]$, it is easy to understand, but when the limit approaches $0$, the monotonicity is not obvious. I wonder how to resolve this.

Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Search about monotone functions on Wikipedia, and you will find monotonically increasing means $x\geq y$ implies $f(x)\geq f(y)$.

@Nuaptan I think the existence of a limit does not imply that for each $t$, $f(x+t)\geq f(x-t)$.

Broad hints: Fort prove this when you have $>0$ instead of $\ge 0$. Apply this to $f(x)+\epsilon e^{x}$ and finally let $\epsilon \to 0$.

@Yviovius I misunderstood your question... The construction $f^s(x)=\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+\varepsilon)-f(x-\varepsilon)}{2\varepsilon}$ is called the symmetric derivative and the proposition you want to prove is a direct consequence of quasi-mean value theorem, proved by Aull in 1967. Ref: https://doi.org/10.2307/2314269
